# Google Place API Search by Web Social

Tags: google-places-api

Google Place API Search by

Web Social

- Has Web Page
- Has Facebook Page
- Has Twitter Page
- Has Yelp Page
- Has Email

How can I search or add these parameters in my search?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Which attribute should I add here to search with only those places which have a Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add those parameters; they are not part of the API. And if they were, you probably would have to code yourself to sift through 
it. I don't think you understand what an API does.

First, you do a search of business that will give you a [preliminary result](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults). From there you select what business you want to find out more (where the information you are looking for would be if it was available through API) then you get the [details on the business](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults).

Comment: dnt take it seriously its client requirement Dude , thanks for your reply